# Firebase email link authentication option not available on firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying the email link authentication for my app on android. When I try to send an email, it gives the error: This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the console.

The document on ([Email link auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth)) says:

To sign in users by email link, you must first enable the Email provider and Email link sign-in method for your Firebase project:

1. In the Firebase console, open the Auth section.
2. On the Sign in method tab, enable the Email/Password provider. Note that email/password sign-in must be enabled to use email link sign-in.
3. In the same section, enable Email link (passwordless sign-in) sign-in method.

I did the first 2 steps. However, there is no passwordless sign-in option available on the console, nor any options under email/password authentication. See attached screenshot. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sent a support ticket to Firebase. Works now.

Comment: It worked after logging out of firebase and logging back in, as support suggested doing.

Answer (score 1):

Click Email/Password again and you will see it:

[image]